# Connection Strings Throw an Error when Connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I'm trying to move an old web application from a Standalone Windows 2008 server to a 2012 R2 server that is in a production environment for a few other web apps.

I moved the SQL Server database to a dedicated SQL Server 2012, and set up a domain user for connection and management of the app. I keep getting the below error, but I'm not sure why the user isn't able to connect.

These are the connection strings with sensitive info changed:

```
<add name="CslaExConnection" 
     connectionString="Database=Databasev3;Server=Server\Instance,50000;User=Domain\User;Password=P@ZZWORD;Enlist=false;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance,50000;Initial Catalog=Databasev3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Domain\User;Password=P@ZZWORD" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ConnectionString1" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance,50000;Initial Catalog=Databasev3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Domain\User;Password=P@ZZWORD" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="Tools" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance,50000;Initial Catalog=Databasev3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Domain\User;Password=P@ZZWORD" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="MySQLConnection" 
     connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=MySQLDB;Uid=root;Pwd=P@ZZWORD;Port=3306;Allow Zero Datetime=True;" 
     providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
<add name="CslaExConnectionSynergyContact" 
     connectionString="Database=goldmine;Server=Server\Instance,50000;User=Domain\User;Password=P@ZZWORD;Enlist=false;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ConnectionString2" 
     connectionString="Data Source=Server\Instance,50000;Initial Catalog=Databasev3;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Domain\User;Password=P@ZZWORD" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And this is the error I receive when I log into the application:

> Server Error in '/md3' Application.
>
> Login failed for user 'domain\user'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'domain\user'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 45:      PagingListFilter filter = new PagingListFilter(info);
>   Line 46:      filter.PageSize = 0;
>   Line 47:      GenericPagedList list = appUser.GetList(filter);
>   Line 48:      DataTable dt = list.Results;
>   Line 49:      if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
>
> Source File: d:\HTTP\wwwroot\synergytools\md3\loginold.aspx.cs    Line: 47
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'domain\user'.]
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +428
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +65
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
>          DFramework.Database.Query.ExecutePagedCommand() in D:\DCPL\Framework\DFramework\Database\Query.cs:508

```
[QueryException: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM vwAppUserList

 WHERE OldUserId = @OldUserId
) count__Query
@OldUserId = 111
]
   DFramework.Database.Query.ExecutePagedCommand() in D:\DCPL\Framework\DFramework\Database\Query.cs:560
   DFramework.Business.BusinessBase.ListData(Query query) in D:\DCPL\Framework\DFramework\Business\BusinessBase.cs:495
   DFramework.Business.BusinessBase.List(Query query) in D:\DCPL\Framework\DFramework\Business\BusinessBase.cs:187
   DFramework.UI.BusinessBase`1.GetList(PagingListFilter filter) in D:\DCPL\Framework\DFramework.UI\BusinessBase.cs:73
   loginold.GetAppUserId(Int32 oldUserId) in d:\HTTP\wwwroot\synergytools\md3\loginold.aspx.cs:47
   loginold.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\HTTP\wwwroot\synergytools\md3\loginold.aspx.cs:22
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8009; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8015

Comment: Does the user have permission to connect? Do they have access to the database? Do you really have the same connection string in your config file seven times, or is this just to obfuscate the details for posting?

Comment: If you can view it, the SQL Server error log should contain more information on why the login failed (specifically, the message text and the 'State' number in the error message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KayZak,

You cannot specify a domain user account and password in the connection string because it's going to treat it like a SQL Server authenticated login.  So, if you are using the domain user account to run the application, your connection string will be in the format below:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=DataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: Oh, alrighty. How would I make sure that application used a specific Windows domain user then, if I don't specify the user?

Comment: @KayZak you can make test connections with .udl file, but if you use "Windows Authentication" then the user will be who execute the application.

Comment: M56 is correct.  Under the assumption you are using IIS, you will have to enable windows authentication for the application and set your application to run as the domain account.  Make sure the domain account login is added in SQL Server also and mapped to the database for the application.

Comment: Alright, that helps. The user is on the SQL instance and mapped to the database, so all I need to it play around with the connection string and make sure the IIS app pool is running under the same domain account?

Comment: Correct.  Since the connection string is in the web config file of the application, it will use the domain account to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the server connection, you can create a empty file in your desktop an save it with `.udl` extension. Now open it, and you can create your connection and test it.

When you finish, if you open the .udl file with notepad you can see the string connection. Remember use "integrated security = SSPI" if you are using domain account.

here you have a tutorial to create and test connections with .udl files: [link .udl](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/)

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks I'll try this tomorrow!